# Replace @mention with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, twitter

I am looking to replace any @mention in a string with `<a href="http://twitter.com/mention">@mention</a>` using Javascript or jQuery. I have the function from the second answer of [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links) and am simply looking to add a further `replacePattern`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function replaceAtMentionsWithLinks ( text ) {
    return text.replace(/@([a-z\d_]+)/ig, '<a href="http://twitter.com/$1">@$1</a>'); 
}
```

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/h6HMY/

Comment: Thankyou very much - just what I wanted.

Comment: Hi; this doesn't work if someone's username has an underscore (only highlights the section before the underscore). Any ideas on how to solve?

Comment: hey @JosephSilber do you have any idea on how to detect arabic and latin names?

Comment: @zianwar - You have to tweak the regex: `/@([a-z\u0600-\u06ff\u0750-\u077f\ufb50-\ufbc1\ufbd3-\ufd3f\ufd50-\ufd8f]‌​|[\ufd92-\ufdc7\ufe70-\ufefc\uFDF0-\uFDFD\d_]+)/ig`